# Can you change info.plist inside a Run Script in Xcode's Build Phase?

Tags: xcode, plist, xcode13

I'm trying to add a value to my `Info.plist` inside a Build Phase Run Script:

```sh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :BuildDate date `date`" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"

# For debugging:
cat "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}" | grep BuildDate
```

This works (as proven by the `cat`), but it seems the result is almost immediately overwritten afterwards, by some other Xcode build step.

Is it simply not possible to modify the `Info.plist` in the Build Phase? I've seen numerous suggestions around the web to do exactly that.

Comment: I also tried `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}`; like the above, I can see it added to the plist in the compiled app, but just prior to the build completing, the new entry disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to modify the `Info.plist` (and not a `plist.info` as I don't know what that is).

It's absolutely possible to create, modify, or delete the `Info.plist` during the Build Phase. However, you need to do so before the build process needs to make use of `Info.plist`. The exact timing of this varies, but the earlier the better - I'd recommend doing so right after the Dependencies step.

I have a [sample Xcode project](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SwiftAuthorizationSample) that does this for a macOS app and a macOS Command Line Tool. It's considerably more complicated than what you're likely trying to do, but it might be helpful to take a look and see how it's configured.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer as it is an accurate answer to my question as it was asked, complete with a repo providing evidence to study, thanks!

However I guess more pertinent to me, and others with the same issue, is why it doesn't work in specific circumstances and/or what can be done to coax it to do so. I believe I have discovered one or two things in this regard so will add another answer describing them.

Answer (score 4):

So I never did really discover exactly why this doesn't work for me but does for others. However, I did come across [a post](https://developer.apple.com/forums//thread/658935?answerId=660023022#660023022) which resolved the issue for me. The solution is to add the `Info.plist` file as an input file in your Build Phase.

`${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}`

[image: Xcode config screenshot]

Comment: In Xcode 15.0 beta I was running into the issue where my build increment script was causing the build to fail because of a sandbox issue.  Adding the info.plist file in the input files field fixed it for me. Bravo!